# Ejecute mysql trigger on a date

Tags: mysql, date, triggers

I'm working on a project that has to pay the employes every month. I'm looking for an option to ejecute a mysql trigger on an specific date. For example, every 28.

I want that when the 28 of june comes, the trigger discount money from one account and add it to the employe account.

Comment: You can use `crontab`

Comment: The trigger is not what you want. Running on a specific date is not the concern of MySQL. As @RyanNghiem said, you can use a crontab rule. And about triggers, look at this: http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-triggers.aspx

Comment: You could use an event https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/event-scheduler.html

Comment: Thank you all. I will try the solutions that you said. =D